# Is second part of map<..,..> stable?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

If we have a `map <int, vector<int> >` are `vector`s moved when the red-black tree of map changes or it stores pointers to `vector`s or something like that and does not move them(else working with maps won't be O(lg n) anymore e.g. if we push_back elements to some `vector`s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this one:
[std::map, pointer to map key value, is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516007/stdmap-pointer-to-map-key-value-is-this-possible)

the *second* top answer:

> Section 23.1.2#8 (associative container requirements):
>
> "The insert members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements."
>
> So *yes* storing pointers to data members of a map element is guaranteed to be valid, unless you remove *that* element.

So, if the references are preserved, the data cannot be copied into a different part of memory. And if that is the case, I don't see the point in performing any copy at all...

Comment: This doesn't address the core question: Is `std::map` allowed to _move_ elements?

Comment: If an element was moved, a pointer/reference to it would get invalidated (I am talking about plain pointers, not iterators). That is why - no - it is not allowed to move elements. ... well, in theory some implementation could copy the object somewhere and then move back to old position, but that would be somewhat strange.

Comment: Though strangely no such requirement is made of `erase`.

Comment: Just for note: The text has been moved to new section p.744, 23.2.4#9 in newer version of standard draft. [N3797, 2013-10-13](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

No, the vectors won't be moved around. The manipulations of the tree just rearrange pointers between the nodes. They don't move nodes or their contents in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the C++03 does not make any guarantees of stability *of the data in the memory*, and this would be an implementation detail (and actually not something you can safely assume without testing).

Note that the preservation of *iterators* to the map and the location of the actual vector in the memory are *completely different things*. The validity of iterators is clearly defined (both when they're valid and when they're not) in the C++ spec, but the actual internal behavior of the tree isn't.

That said, any decent compiler (for release builds/with optimizations enabled) would optimize the implementation to not actually copy the vector when it's being moved around in the tree, and C++11 implementations of `std::map` would use move semantics to guarantee that behavior.

What you cannot assume is that internally only pointers are moved.

Comment: `std::map<K, V>` is required to be a node-based container in all revisions of the standard, i.e. nodes which aren't erased from the map stay put in memory: neither iterators nor pointers to map elements become invalidated until the node is erased or the map is destroyed.

Comment: But it also preserves references (plain pointers), not just iterators. This allows you to argue about memory. Unless there is some strange memory address virtualisation...